# Recording audio using i2s mic results to pure noise when interfaced with Raspberry PI 3 (both I2S mic and I2S speaker)

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-jessie, i2s

I followed Adafruit's guide for setting up the [I2S mic](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-i2s-mems-microphone-breakout?view=all) with raspberry pi 3 loaded with precompiled image of Raspbian Jessie for the [3.5in PiTFT](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-pitft-3-dot-5-touch-screen-for-raspberry-pi?view=all).

Also, I'm using another **I2S** device which is the  [Speaker Bonnet](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-speaker-bonnet-for-raspberry-pi) and it is working fine.

but when recording an audio by:

```
arecord -D plughw:1 -c1 -r 48000 -f S32_LE -t wav -V mono -v file.wav
```

and playing the recorded audio which is *file.wav* by: `aplay file.wav`, all I get is noise.

Comment: You're probably going to have to provide more detail than this. Putting exactly what you did into your question usually helps.

Comment: @Brick, ok I edited my question.

Comment: Hy bgsuello, did you manage to get the playback and the recording working on the same board. I am facing some profound struggles: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/90647/i2s-recording-combined-with-i2s-playback

Comment: You could SCP the `file.wav` to your computer to play it back. Plus you can upload a wav-file from the internet and play it back on your pi. Like this you know if the noise is coming from the mic or the speaker driver. `scp pi@192.168.1.110:/home/pi/file.wav /Users/yourname/Desktop/file.wav` or the other way around (of course you'll need to insert proper paths and IP address of your pi).

Comment: Yes, but i forget to create a doc on how did i do it since i was in a hurry. All i can remember was I made a new device tree overlay combining both i2s device as input and output. I did not use the provided drivers by adafruit.

Answer (score 1):

@bgsuello I also faced the similar problem microphone was getting detected and was showing it is recording but it was only recording noise, during playback as well noise only could be heard.
Reason behind this for me was as in I2S signal integrity matters, as you must be using jumper wires for connecting microphone with raspberry pi, try use small and good quality wires and I will suggest solder the microphone with single strand wires at the back side of the raspberry pi you will get crisp and clear sound.
It worked for me and others as well hope it will help you also.